# Can I make an ultrasound machine using dust particles of different sizes sticking to paper with static electricity?

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform, ultrasound

If I surrounded an object (to be scanned) with cylinders of paper - each sheet of paper with different sized dust particles sticking to it through static electricity, and then struck the test object with a hammer and made it vibrate would different wavelengths of sound from the test object
shake off different sized dust particles and create an image of what is inside the test object or of the test object itself?

Comment: What should make the dust particles "create an image"? Do you think about something like Chladni figures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni#Chladni_figures) in 3D?

Comment: I was thinking that something inside the test object  with a different density would mainly emit one wavelength or a small range of wavelength s that would show up on one sheet of paper or maybe two or three sheets

Comment: That would only be the case if the object inside the test object is weakly coupled to the test object itself. Usually, however, there will be a more or less stronger coupling and the eigen-frequencies of this assembly will be a complicated result of both objects and their coupling stiffness. In any case will the object emit a lot of frequencies, not just one, and the shapes will be three-dimensional. It is unclear how you want to map this 1:1 to a surface. You probably could, if phases could be recorded (that is the principle of NMR tomography), but with dust particles... hardly imaginable.

Comment: By the way, also holography works this way, but again, by keeping track of relative phases.